# how to increase vm memory for NetBeans plug-in started from NB

Tags: memory, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, permgen

I couldn't find info on how to do it. Increasing memory settings for NetBeans itself is the matter of updating `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf` on my Mac.

However, I'd like to increase the memory settings for the vm process that is started when I run my plugin from NetBeans. Without bumping the memory I'm hitting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in about 30 secs playing with the UI. This situation only happens on my Mac, on Windows 7 I don't have that issue :)

My platform is:
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
MacOs 10.6.8
NetBeans 7.0.1

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set JVM command line arguments in your `platform.properties` file using the following:

```
run.args.extra=<your-args>
```

This only works during development, so for production you'll need to set them in the app's `.conf` file (just like NetBeans' `.conf`). See the following FAQ for more info:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqPassCommandLineArgumentsAtDevTime

In the future, you'll probably have better luck with questions regarding NetBeans Plugins if you asked them in the [NetBeans Platform Users](http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html) forum.

Comment: Works with one gotcha: the vm parameters must be prefixed with -J. Example:

`run.args.extra=-J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`